# Quelles sont les nuances entre « face à », « en face de » et « devant »

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, reformulation

Je suis

…face à l’hôtel.

…en face de l’hôtel.

…devant l’hôtel.

Il y a une personne

…face à moi.

…en face de moi.

…devant moi.

Je t’attends

…face au parc d’attractions.

…en face du parc d’attraction.

…devant le parc d’attraction.

Peut-on employer indifféremment « face à » et « en face de » pour signifier que le visage d’un animé est tourné vers un objet. S’il s’agit d’une personne et d’un objet, est-ce que la face de ce dernier, par exemple la couverture d’un livre, doit nécessairement être tourné vers le visage de la personne. S’il est question de deux êtres animés, est-ce que les deux doivent obligatoirement se faire face ou est-ce qu'il suffit que l’un d’entre eux ait le visage orienté vers le dos de l’autre?

Michel est assis en face de Nicole, les deux se font face. (Face-à-face).

Nicole se retourne et a dorénavant le visage orienté vers le mur. (Elle tourne le dos à Michel).

On peut toujours dire que Michel est assis en face de Nicole, mais il n’en va pas de même pour Nicole. Nicole est maintenant devant Michel, de dos.

Du point d’un observateur extérieur au loin ayant le visage orienté vers les deux personnes concernées, Nicole peut-elle être considérée comme étant en face de Michel?

Comment: Lié: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20175/usage-devant-or-en-face-de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oui, « en face de » et « face à » peuvent exprimer la même idée. Par exemple, en parlant d'un groupe de promeneurs qui sont arrivé sur une place, devant un hôtel et qui s'attardent à cet endroit pour observer les environs les deux phrases suivantes sont équivalentes du point de vue sens, il n'est pas nécessaire que la partie antérieure de ces personnes soit tournée vers l'hôtel.

- Nous sommes en face d'un hôtel, l'Hôtel du Commerce, sur une grande place, vous le connaissez ?
- Nous sommes  face àun hôtel,  l'Hôtel du Commerce, sur une grande place, vous le connaissez ?

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/face)) 2. En face de
> a) Du même côté que la face d'une personne, que la partie antérieure, visible, d'une chose.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/face)) 3. Face à
> a) La face, la partie antérieure du corps tournée vers. Nous avançons face au soleil. C'est contre toute logique que j'ai décidé de faire du plein est (Saint-Exup., Terre hommes,1939, p. 220).Trois musulmans faisaient leurs génuflexions rituelles face à La Mecque (Ambrière, Gdes vac.,1946, p. 168).
> b) **P. ext.** Du même côté que la partie antérieure, visible, de quelque chose

On vérifie par quelques ngram comment les définitions sont reconnues/appliquées, « en face de » devant normalement être utilisé pour les personnes.

[image]

[étais face à lui,étais en face de lui](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A9tais+face+%C3%A0+lui%2C%C3%A9tais+en+face+de+lui&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A9tais%20en%20face%20de%20lui%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C3%A9tais%20en%20face%20de%20lui%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Ce n'est plus vrai pour « [suis face à lui,suis en face de lui](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suis+face+%C3%A0+lui%2Csuis+en+face+de+lui&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuis%20face%20%C3%A0%20lui%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuis%20en%20face%20de%20lui%3B%2Cc0) ».

Ce n'est plus vrai non plus pour « [suis face à elle,suis en face d'elle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suis+face+%C3%A0+elle%2Csuis+en+face+d%27elle&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuis%20face%20%C3%A0%20elle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuis%20en%20face%20d%27%20elle%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csuis%20face%20%C3%A0%20elle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuis%20en%20face%20d%27%20elle%3B%2Cc0) ». L'ère moderne chamboule cela, comme on peut le voir à partir de la page suivante : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22suis%20face%20%C3%A0%20elle%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

[image]

On trouve un état de chose similaire pour « suis face à eux,suis en face d'eux ».

[image]

L'expression qui assure que le côté antérieur de l'une de deux persones  est tourné vers le côté antérieur de l'autre ou que le côté antérieur d'une personne est tourné vers le côté antérieur d'une chose est la suivante.

> (TLFi) **faire face à** 1. [Le suj. désigne une pers.] Présenter ou tourner la face, la partie antérieure du corps vers quelqu'un ou quelque chose.

- Ils faisaient face à un terrain vague sur lequel ils ne voulaient pas s'aventurer.

L'emploi pronominal est possible pour les personnes.

- Ils se font face et se regardent méchamment.